# Name of a design pattern involving cross-casting

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, casting, selenium-webdriver

In using Selenium WebDriver, I have noticed a pattern in their API with their class hierarchy.

The api is set up like this:

```
Interface A {
   void doAStuff();
}
Interface B {
   void doBStuff();
}
Interface C {
   void doCStuff();
}
Class X implements A, B, C {
   ...
}
Class Y implements A, B, C {
   ...
}
Class Z implements A, B, C {
   ...
}
```

The implementation looks like this:

```
public void doStuffWithImplementationsOfA(A a) {
   a.doAStuff();
   B b = (B) a;
   b.doBStuff();
   C c = (C) a;
   c.doCStuff();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   A a = new X();
   doStuffWithImplementationsOfA(a);
}
```

As you can see, Interfaces A, B, and C do not extend one another at all, But in the API, all implementations of A also implement B and C, thus allowing cross-casting.  Specifically, in Selenium, all implementations of WebDriver (like FirefoxDriver and ChromeDriver) also implement several other common unrelated Interfaces (HasInputDevices, JavascriptExecutor, etc.); likewise all implementations of WebElement implement other common unrelated Interfaces (like Locatable).  This not only allows, but requires cross-casting between Interfaces to access various methods in each implementation.

**My Question, in three parts:**

1. Does this kind of hierarchy qualify as a Design Pattern?
2. If so, does it have a name?
3. What are the benefits/drawbacks of designing an API this way (as opposed to just making the C extend B, and B extend A)?

**EDIT:  Here is a diagram (not exhaustive) of the WebDriver API Hierarchy.**

[image]

Comment: There's probably a name for it, but assuming that `A` `B` and `C` aren't dependent on each other, don't enforce it.  The extra characters of typing each interface name is a great tradeoff for the clean code it gives.  (Just because I have something that implements `Iterable` and `Serializable` doesn't mean I should make one that extends both)

Comment: This looks horrible.  I hope I never have to do this...ever.

Comment: @MrTi "The extra characters ... are a great tradeoff for the clean code": This seems to be a good reason for designing the API this way; it provides cohesion in the API.  Cross-casting seems to be a drawback in and of itself though, so I was wondering if there are any more benefits to this design, or if the benefit of cohesion could be expounded upon in this case?

Comment: If I want to only extend 1 or 2 of them, but not all three.  For example, a driver is not enforced to allow the taking of screenshots. (They can release a driver that doesn't take screenshots with a todo to implement in the future)

Comment: @MrTi Good observation.  I see that RemoteWebDriver and HTMLUnitWebDriver do not implement TakesScreenshot.  I'm attaching a diagram to my question that shows this.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a `new` thing - it is a common mechanism in Java. Take a look at `Iterable`, `Comparable`, `Serializable`. Many classes will implement one or more of these and work fine.

More recently, with the advent of generics, you can use something like this which makes more sense and does not require that horrid casting:

```
interface A {
  void doAStuff();

}

interface B {
  void doBStuff();

}

interface C {
  void doCStuff();

}

public static <T extends A & B & C> void doStuff (T to) {
  to.doAStuff();
  to.doBStuff();
  to.doCStuff();
}
```

1. Does this kind of hierarchy qualify as a Design Pattern?

   Not that I know of.
2. If so, does it have a name?

   See 1.
3. What are the benefits/drawbacks of designing an API this way (as opposed to just making the C extend B, and B extend A)?

   If the interfaces are not a hierarchy then there is no reason to make them so. See my `Iterable` and `Comparable` above.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, and it's a good point.  But I think in the case of the Selenium API, it's different.  For example, all WebElements are things that have Coordinates, so an argument could be made that the WebElement Interface should extend Locatable (which has the getCoordinates() method).  However, it does not.  To get coordinates on a WebElement, one must first cross-cast to a Locatable.  This is not the same situation as Iterable, Comparable, and Serializeable as there are plenty of situations where implementing only one of these is desirable.

Comment: Looks to me like they were being lazy. OldCurmudgeon's `public static <T extends A & B & C>` method looks useful. And if all `WebElement` implementations must be able to `getCoordinates()` then yes, they should've had `WebElement` extend `Locatable`. The fact that they didn't implies that not all `WebElement`s are `Locatable`.

Comment: @CorayThan  Good point, because the implication that not all WebElements are Locatable is wrong.

Comment: @CorayThan - I am not sure I would go so far as calling them lazy. I would say they are choosing a fine-grained approach to interfaces. For example in `Go` there is an [interface](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) called `Reader` that has a method `Read`, just a small part of the `io` package. Again a fine-grained approach which works very well.